# Sub-gradients of non-Convex Functions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I was wondering, why are sub-gradients only mentioned for convex functions? What happens when the assumption of convexity is relaxed?

EDIT: I get that for functions which have local/global maxima, the concept of sub-gradient doesn't make sense, but is there a sort of "supremum-set-like-upper-gradient" analogy?

I am just beginning to learn about sub-gradients, so and introductory answer is appreciated.

Also, in multivariable calculus, we use $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ frequently. Does the notation of sub-gradient, $\partial f$, relate to the other?

Comment: There is a notion of sub differential for locally Lipschitz functions. And it can be extended beyond that. Many of the rules of calculus carry over, with some interpretation. For example, at a local minimum, we have $0 \in \partial f(x)$. One reference is Frank H. Clarke, "Optimization and Nonsmooth Analysis".

Comment: The definition of subgradient doesn't require our function to be convex. But subgradients are especially useful when studying convex functions because, for example, a convex function is guaranteed to be subdifferentiable at any point in the relative interior of its effective domain. Note that if $ f $ is convex and differentiable at $ x $ then $\partial f (x) = \{ \nabla f (x)\} $.